# Can I download ubuntu 64bit on my windows 7 32bit?

Tags: upgrade, windows, windows-7, 64-bit, 32-bit

As the topic says I'm pretty sure that I want to replace my windows 7 with ubuntu but I need to know if I can upgrade my OS to 64bit from 32bit windows 7.

Thanks

Comment: You can download an image of Ubuntu 64bit, and replace Windows, or install Ubuntu alongside Windows. However, you can not "upgrade my OS to 64bit from 32bit windows 7", whatever that means.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)

Answer (score 1):

When you want to replace Windows with Ubuntu, it does not matter which version you install.
Important is that your PC has a CPU which supports 64-bit, what most probably will be the case.
So yes, most probably you can install the recommended Ubuntu 64-bit edition on your computer.

Note : You cannot upgrade the operating system from Windows to Ubuntu, you have to install it.
[Download Ubuntu Desktop 64-bit](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) and install it by following the [Ubuntu installation instructions](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop).